# Citing someone else's idea??? (but not published work)

Tags: publications, citations, writing

**I will preface that this is in regards to a Christian devotional to study scriptures from the Bible.** I was tasked to put together a 25 day devotional that will be published physically and online by my church. I was given a copy of a similar type of devotional from a friend who gave me permission to use however I would like. I basically used it as the bones of the devotional; however, I have rewritten a bit of the material with our particular "church language", as well as changed, added and removed a bit of the content and some of the ideas. All the original studied scriptures are the same. The problem is that I do not know exactly how to cite this person's work. They did indeed write the basis of what we will be publishing; albeit, I do not have a publish date from them, or even a title of their work. I just want to cite their work and ideas properly as a majority of the basic content is not my own. Thoughts please!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about academia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to cite their work and ideas properly as a majority of the basic content is not my own.

Given that the majority of the content is not yours, you may want to make the person a co-author (or co-editor, etc.). That would appropriately recognize the work the other individual has made in the work that you have adapted.

Alternatively, if you feel most of your work has been editorial rather than creative, you could state:

> by X (arr. by Y),

where X is your friend.